# Kendo UI - How do I modify a Kendo template in JavaScript

Tags: kendo-ui

I am trying to modify a Kendo UI template at runtime in JavaScript.

My template contains a '103' (second line) which I want to dynamically change within JavaScript.

```html
<script type="text/x-kendo-tmpl" id="srcBldgTemplate">
     #if(data.BuildingName == '103'){#
        <div  class="item click" data="${BuildingID}">
            <input id=chkSrcBldgMain type="checkbox" class="click" checked="true"  onclick="filterDataSrcBldg(this,'SrcBuildingID');" />
            <span class="checkbox">#:BuildingName#</span>
        </div>
    #}else{#
    <div class="item click" data="${BuildingID}">
        <input type="checkbox" class="click"  onclick="filterDataSrcBldg(this,'SrcBuildingID');" />
        <span class="checkbox">#:BuildingName#</span>
    </div>
    #}#       
</script>
```

The code I use to modify works to replace the element's html.

```js
$("#srcBldgTemplate").html().replace('103', $(currChkBldg).next().html());
```

However, when I run an alert afterwards on $("#srcBldgTemplate").html(), I keep getting 103 in the template instead of the new value.

How do I dynamically change the template and use the updated template value when Kendo reloads the template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that `.html()` is a *GET* method. It only gets a copy of your template, so when you replace the value, it changes the copy instance but not the original value.

In order to *SET* the new template, you have to use `.html(htmlString)`

So do something like this:

```js
var newTemplate = $("#srcBldgTemplate").html().replace('103', $(currChkBldg).next().html());
$("#srcBldgTemplate").html(newTemplate);
```

Get and replace the template, store it in a temp variable. Then you can set that temp variable as the new template.

Comment: Thank you.  Looks like that was the issue.  I also noticed that I had to add the template init function inside the edit event handler of the Kendo UI grid where I am having the issue.